# Clearlinux docker container fails on CentOS7

Tags: linux, docker, kernel, centos7, clearlinux

I'm trying to run clearlinux docker container on CentOS7. It launches successfully but basic fs operations fail:

```
$ docker run -it clearlinux:latest /bin/bash -c "ls -ld /"
ls: cannot access '/': Operation not permitted
```

However on CentOS8 and Ubuntu there is no such issue. It works fine:

```
$ docker run -it clearlinux:latest /bin/bash -c "ls -ld /"
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Apr 14 14:18 /
```

I'm installing docker this way: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/

I've tried three different kernels: 5.6.4, 4.4.219, 3.10.0

Also I've tried both ext4 and xfs as Backing filesystem for overlay2.

Probably there is an issue with el7 kernel or el7 docker-ce package. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's interesting that some of commands are working fine inside container, for example find:


`find / -maxdepth 1 -ls`

Comment: Created issue in ClearLinux github repository:
https://github.com/clearlinux/distribution/issues/1916